# File permissions for fopen in write mode - PHP

Tags: php, fopen, fputcsv

I have a PHP script that writes some rows to a CSV file:

```
$fp = fopen($csv, 'w');
```

I'm using mode 'w' so that it will create the file if it doesn't exist, however the file is automatically given **644** permissions even though I gave 777 to the whole /var/www/html/ directory (not a good idea but suitable for testing).

How can I write to the file and give it permissions beforehand? Or is there a better way to give write permissions?

Comment: are you having trouble writing to the file? 644 should be fine for writing as the owner has read/write permissions.

Comment: @MattK It seems to create the csv under the owner of 'Apache' which is different than the owner of all the other files in the directory

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php

Comment: Take a look at `umask`, which is actually a specification from Unix/Linux system.

Comment: This was 11 years ago but thanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create the file before hand and set permissions:

```
touch('/file/path/here');
chmod('/file/path/here', 0775);
fopen('/file/path/here', 'w');
```

But, this should not be an issue. If the PHP/Apache user is creating the file using `fopen`, they have permissions to write to it.

Comment: The owner seems to change to 'apache'. I don't want to hardcode an owner into PHP because the domain might change.

Comment: Did you experience any different behavior with the code above?